# NSButton not showing image nor text at runtime

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, macos-catalina, xcode11.1

I have a Mac app developed 6 years ago. Today, I opened the source code (in XCode 11.1, macOS Catalina 10.15.3) and run the app. The Play button is not showing the Play image as before.

[image]

Here are its properties.

[image]

Can someone please tell me what's wrong?

Comment: There's been a ton of subtle UI changes through the years ... just change the width and height constraint until if fits

Comment: If it was 6 years ago, there's a chance there's some interaction with auto layout that's causing issues. It doesn't look like there are any constraints in your xib from this screenshot. Try calling -[NSButton sizeToFit] on the control in viewDidLoad. Also experiment with different values for that style drop down. "Bevel" might be deprecated (or it may be the default, I'm not in fromt of Xcode right now).